# Sql Query with "IN" clause across two tables and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

**Table1**:

```
 Id | Mapping_Id (INT)
 --- ---------------
  1    1001
  2    1002
  3    1003
  4    1004
```

**Table2**:

```
 Name | ResultId (nvarchar(Max))
 ----  -------------------------
  AB    1001,1002,1003,1004
```

Now, i need query which give sum of Id from Table1, by using **Table1** and **Table2** on columns **Mapping_Id** and **ResultId**

i.e: something like **Select sum(A.Id),B.Name from Table1 A,Table2 B where A.Mapping_Id in (B.ResultId)**

expected result:

```
 Count | ResultId (nvarchar(Max))
 -----  -------------------------
  10       AB
```

Comment: Why do you need the sum of an id field if I may ask?

Comment: Don't store column values as comma separated

Comment: or else in place of Id, i might be having some price corresponding to those id's......@Nico Van Belle

Comment: It's result set of some other function, it has to be that way .........@Ullas

Comment: @Ullas Never say never.

Comment: As mentioned, comma separated values are not a good idea in a sql database. Even more so when you need to use the separate values in your queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT SUM(Table1.id), Table2.Name
from Table1
join Table2 on CHARINDEX(cast(Table1.Mapping_id as varchar), Table2.ResultID)>0
group by Table2.Name
```

Comment: example: if mapping_id = '1', and resultId = '1001' => query result will be wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
Select sum(A.Id),B.Name from Table1 A,Table2 B where A.Mapping_Id in (select value from SplitDelimited(B.ResultId,','))
```

Use SplitDelimited fuction for that..

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitDelimited]
(   
    @List nvarchar(MAX),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(1)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table (
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Value nvarchar(MAX)
)

AS
BEGIN
    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
    Begin 
        if(len(@List) > 0)
        begin
            Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
            Select 
                Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1))) 
            Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
        end
    End 

    Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
    Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

    Return
END
```